# Location of dhclient.conf

Tags: rhel, dhcp

I need to check the client DHCP settings, which I expect to be in the file  `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, but there is no such files there.

What is the location of this file in RHEL 6, on 64 bit?

Comment: The question has been asked last year, I know, but i just wanted to add my two cents: why not use `locate dhclient.conf` or `find / -iname dhclient.conf -print` ? or even simpler but dirtier `locate dhclient` or `locate dhcp`

Answer (score 10):

A trick I'll often use is to take a look at the output of this command, here I'm running it on CentOS 6, but it should still be applicable to you on RHEL as well:

```
$ ps -eaf | grep dhcli
root      1044     1  0 Jan17 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/dhclient -1 -q -cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf -lf /var/lib/dhclient/dhclient-eth0.leases -pf /var/run/dhclient-eth0.pid eth0
root      3771  3738  0 19:00 pts/0    00:00:00 grep dhcli
```

If you notice in the output, the file you're looking for is called `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf`, and not `dhclient.conf`. But this is only telling you part of the story. If you're intending to inject additional settings into `dhclient` when it starts up then refer to the official RHEL 6 documentation here, titled: [14.3. Configuring a DHCP Client](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/s1-dhcp-configuring-client.html).

Also if you consult the man page for `dhclient` you'll notice this bit for the `-cf` switch:

```
-cf <config-file>
      Path to the client configuration file.  If unspecified, the default 
      /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf is used.
```

So the file `dhclient.conf` isn't the file you're likely looking for, it's whatever interface you're running `dhclient` on, in this case `eth0`, so the file would be `dhclient-eth0.conf`.

#### Digging deeper

If you take a look at the startup scripts for networking you'll likely come across this file, `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifup-eth`. Peeking inside can show you what's going on if you're interested:

```
...
# allow users to use generic '/etc/dhclient.conf' (as documented in manpage!) 
# if per-device file doesn't exist or is empty
if [ -s /etc/dhcp/dhclient-${DEVICE}.conf ]; then
   DHCLIENTCONF="-cf /etc/dhcp/dhclient-${DEVICE}.conf";
elif [ -s /etc/dhclient-${DEVICE}.conf ]; then
   DHCLIENTCONF="-cf /etc/dhclient-${DEVICE}.conf";
else
   DHCLIENTCONF='';
fi;
...
```

So you could create a `dhclient.conf` file of your own and remove the interface specific one that was created for you by the system.

Answer (score 5):

RHEL 6 and newer uses NetworkManager by default which creates dhclient configuration on the fly.

You will find the file in `/var/lib/NetworkManager/dhclient-*.conf` but you can't change this file as it's autgenerated. Check NetworkManager documentation about how to set various flags.

If you turn NetworkManager off, then sim's answer applies.

Answer (score 1):

On a fresh RHEL 7.5 install, /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf doesn't exist, but if you create it containing just the options you want, that seems to work. I'll bet it works for RHEL 6 as well.