# Permanently change IP address on CentOS machine

Tags: linux, centos, network-interface

I have virtual machine running CentOS 6.6 in it.
I want to permanently change the IP address for my network interface `eth1`, however the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` is not present.
Any other option for this, or what might be the reason for file not being there?

Comment: Check my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/680286/295286). Pay attention though, that `dhclient.conf` file on CentOS is in different location. Refer [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/111971/85039). Also [this](http://serverfault.com/q/672845)

Answer (score 0):

If such file is not present we can create the file with that name.
What I did is :
1. `cp /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Auto_eth0 /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Auto_eth1`
2. This file contains Hardware address , so get the hardware address (`HWADDR`)  for your corresponding network interface using : `vim /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` and update it in the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Auto_eth1` file as `HWADDR = <hardware address>`
          Another way to get Hardware address of corresponding network interface (`eth1` in this case is) `ifconfig -a | grep -i --color hwaddr`
3. If `ONBOOT` option is set to `no`, change it to : `ONBOOT=yes`
4. Reboot the system