# Where is dhclient.conf in Fedora 22

Tags: fedora, dns, dhcp

Before you mark it as a duplicated please listen to the problem. I took a lot of time searching on this issue and found very similar problems but none of them solved it because the suppose solution files simply doesn't exist.

I have two interfaces on my Fedora 22 machine, which one as a different DNS server. At the `/etc/resolv.conf` the first nameserver is the nameserver of my school and then comes my nameserver. I want to solve DNS queries of `mydomain.com` that my school domain doesn't know. On this scenario the query must be asked to my DNS server. I solved this issue on other machines by updating `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` with `supersede` or `prepend` but at this machine this file doesn't exist. Any suggestions?

It might be worth to tell that I'm using NetworkManager service to configure those interfaces.

I found that  `/etc/dhcp/dhclient-eth0.conf` might be what I'm looking for. Does the option `supersede` is acceptable here too?!

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111971/location-of-dhclient-conf

Comment: Now there are answers at https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/110664/where-can-i-find-dhclientconf-on-fedora-26/

Answer (score 0):

For Fedora :You should check on /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0/enp2s0. 
When you edited ifcfg-eth0/enp2s0
 BOOTPROTO=dynamic as your dhcp client.
If I am not mistaken.
You mentioned dhcpclient.conf was on ubuntu/debian. 
Dont mess up between Ubuntu and Fedora distro.

Comment: I don't want to mess up with protocol